# I cannot find my mistake in python

Tags: python, class

I am trying to write a problem with classes in python. I am a beginner. I cannot realized where the problem is. When I run the code I received this error:

```
  File "D:/Facultate/Python/Bibliotek_Classe/Classe.py", line 43, in add_client
    self.client_list.append(client)
AttributeError: 'CrudOperationOnClient' object has no attribute 'client_list'
```

And this is the class where it is supposed to be a mistake. Thank you very much!

[this is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltRMw.jpg)

Comment: Could you format the code? The help for the format is explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) also, where are you defining client_list?

Comment: Please show us the code where you call `something.add_client(some_client)`, especially how you create or declare `something`.

Comment: Please do not attempt to post code in a comment - not only does it look bad, but it's also not the right place for it. To make changes to your post, you can simply [edit] it.

Comment: `__int__` != `_init__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write def `__init__(self):` instead of `__int__(self):`

Comment: Question should be closed as a typo, not answered